# View source on smart phones?

Tags: mobile

Is this something that should be integrated in smart phone browsers for the future of web developers, programmers and designers? I know there's the Snoopy bookmarklet (and maybe other options I'm not aware of) but I think for the sake of trying to check broken links while not next to your home computer it would help me.